# BPEL vs Domain Events for integrating several bounded contexts

Tags: java, c#, domain-driven-design, soa, bpel

Is there a place for BPEL when doing Domain Driven Design?

As far as I understand from Vaughn Vernon's [Implementing Domain Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321834577) we should use Domain Events to communicate between different bounded contexts.

Does that exclude the usage of BPEL? or do they solve different problems?

What I'm trying to achieve is to have each bounded context run as a service and use domain events to communicate between these services. Another team member (not familiar with DD) suggested using BPEL instead.

Comment: Not familiar with BPEL, any chance to use BPEL as the implementation mechanism and keep domain separated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that if BPEL were to be used at all, you would use it in a specific bounded context. In any case, you'd want to use an event-based collaboration model between your bounded contexts (assuming that they are well aligned with your sub-domains), as well as UI composition as needed to decrease the amount of data that needs to be passed between them.

The reason I'd say not to use BPEL to coordinate bounded contexts is that it will create an additional place where domain logic may be written. The whole idea of a bounded context is that everything that deals with the given ubiquitous language stays within the boundary.

I'd say that the use of BPEL (and other integration) tools can be appropriate within a bounded context for the purpose of integrating multiple 3rd-party systems and other cases where we want to provide some kind of UI that a semi-technical domain expert could use to tweak the behavior of some aspects of that bounded context.

Comment: Thanks Udi for the answer. It was actually ur blog posts that got me started on domain events. Why would you say the BPEL should be used in a single bounded context? I was under the impression that BPEL is better suited for integration between different bounded contexts! I think this point could be crucial to decide which approach to take.

Comment: Expanded on my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Udi. Actually what my colleague's aim was to create a long running process. Our system is used to fulfill orders (order placed->confirmed->supplied->shipped). Each of the transition states will happen in a separate bounded context and he says that BPEL can "easily" be used to co-ordinate these transitions. I'm not sure if BPEL can accomplish what he wants, but if you were in my place how would you counter this argument?

Comment: What he's describing is an orchestration approach which will undermine the autonomy of each of the bounded contexts.